# Prove that the operator $T:X\to Y$ satisfies $\|T^n\|\leqslant \|T\|^n$.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed spaces and $T:X\to Y$ a linear operator. How do I prove this for $T$? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Prove it for $T$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you can't compose $T$ with itself, unless $X=Y$.

Let $A,B \in \mathscr{B}(X)$, i.e. bounded linear operators. Then, $\forall x \in X$, we have that
$$\lVert Ax \rVert \leqslant \lVert A \rVert \lVert x \rVert$$
And also
$$\lVert A Bx \rVert \leqslant \lVert A \rVert \lVert Bx \rVert \leqslant \lVert A \rVert \lVert B\rVert \lVert x \rVert$$
Which means that
$$\lVert AB \rVert \leqslant \lVert A \rVert \lVert B \rVert$$
i.e. the operator norm is submultiplicative. Now you can use induction to prove what you want.